# H2 increment column

Tags: sql, h2

Using a H2 database, I would like to increment a value with **one** query. In MySQL I would go for something like

```
INSERT INTO counts SET id = 1, c = 1 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c = c + 1;
```

H2 does not support `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, but I read about `MERGE INTO`. However, I haven't figured out, if and how it can be used to increment a value. Is it possible? Is there another way?

Comment: In the latest trunk of H2 (not released yet), `on duplicate key update` is supported when using the MySQL mode.

Comment: Good to know, I'll have an eye on it. Thanks!

Comment: This version is now released, so I guess I will add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With H2 version 1.3.176 and newer, when using the MySQL mode, the statement in the question works. To use the MySQL mode, append `;mode=mysql` to the database URL.